# Does Soul Memory Affect Co-op or Only Invasions?

Tags: dark-souls-2

If I'm understanding correctly, Soul Memory, the collective accumulation of all souls ever obtained, ensures that the players that you meet in multiplayer are of a similar experience level compared to you.

In Dark Souls, connectability was determined purely through character Soul Level.  Does Soul Level still come into play or is it only determined by Soul Memory?

I read that invasion is affected by Soul Memory, but I figured it would be silly if co-op was also affected by it and was hoping to find out if co-op was actually based on soul level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namco has a knowledgebase article stating it does.

http://support.namcobandaigames.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/420/0/dark-souls-ii---im-having-trouble-with-summoningsinvasions

> Total amount of souls collected and levels - A character's total number of souls is factored in during summonings/invasions (generally you must be within 50,000 souls of the person you're invading/co-opping with and your level must be within +/- 10 levels).

The 50,000 souls requirement seems to be completely wrong, though.

According to fextralife:

http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Summon+Range+Calculator

> 1) Your soul memory plus or minus 25%.
>   2) Your Soul Level plus or minus 10, AND THEN a further plus or minus 10%.
>   Both 1) and 2) must comply between the two players for online play.
>   When using a name-engraved ring the percentage of souls allowed jumps from 25% to 30%

Answer (score 4):

I have had some problems with soul memory.  I gamed with a friend perfectly throughout the day then all of a sudden we could not summon each other. 
The difference was I was using a ring which gave me more souls.  (it might be soul memory or a coincidence, will do some more research)
We had the exact same soul level,  using God rings,  regional lock was off (we live in different regions)  and communicated by pc to ensure we were putting the signs where we needed.
 So yes I believe soul memory does effect Co-op.  (again it might of been an annoying coincidence that we could not Co-op once my soul memory became larger)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the research.  I may leave the question open until there is a definitive answer.  Soul memory affecting co-op seems to be a very poor decision though.  You would think that due to the extended longevity of characters through being able to respec would lead to the assumption that soul memory shoud **not** come into play with co-op and instead encourages twinking.

Comment: I've had roughly the same experience:
I was pretty much running the game completely co-op with a friend.  He wasn't able to play for a day, so I thought I would go buy some buff items.

I'm now at 950K Soul Memory, he's at 600K.  We cannot summon each other now.

He's going to grind to the level suggested by Fextralife's Co-Op calculator.  I'll try to update this comment when he catches up to what the calculator says is acceptable Soul Memory range.

* See answers below.  This comment is more for testing the 25-30% range from the link in the answer than providing the answer.

Comment: So I can confirm that the buddy I wasn't able to play with can now be summoned/summon me when he reached within 30% of my Soul Memory.

The fextralife calculator was pretty accurate.  We weren't able to co-op at first, but within a few more thousand souls we got together on the first try.

Answer (score -2):

It effects coop plain and simple. If you are not within range for soul memory or soul level you will not connect. Its happened to me and a friend like it has to you. People who say it doesn't are trolls. There is a calculator that tells you exactly how it works and calculates it for you. Soul Memory is a Horrible Addition.

Comment: The calculator has already been mentioned and explained in greater detail.  DS2 has been out for less than a week so this question is asking for researched answers about whether or not soul memory affects co-op.

Comment: Soul memory is an awesome addition. Otherwise you'd have SL 20 twinks ganking noobs forever and ever like in Dark Souls 1.